# Dealing with rows and columns in C# datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, northwind

I'm dealing with some dataGridView forms but I have some problems that I don't understand well

So, this is what I'm missing.

[image]

How to show data in those columns - Customers, Employees and Shippers?

It's Northwind DB and simple form with classic datagridview.

Function returns list of all orders from DB. I know how to remove columns but in this case I need to show ALL data from that.

Do I need to play with my query or with form C# code?

Sorry, here's the code:

Query

```
public static List<Orders> getAllOrd()
{
  var query = (from o in Model.DM_Class.dc.Orders
               select o).ToList();
  return query;
}
```

Form

```
private void frm_Orders_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgv_Orders.DataSource = OrdersService.getAllOrd();
        }
```

How to manage the ones in that columns to show them also?

Comment: Well Gabrijel you need to show the code..that's like asking me what the winning lotto numbers are before purchasing a ticket.. `Show your Code as well as the Query you are using`

Comment: @DJKRAZE sorry, question edited..

Comment: when using List<> as a DataSource, `List class does not support notifications from objects within its collection` try changing this `public static List<Orders> getAllOrd()` to `public static BindingList<Orders> getAllOrd()` also explain what you are truly wanting to return. where is the `.Where` condition in your query..?

Comment: I need to return all data from Products table but in that table are also information about customers, shippers etc who are in other tables. I've tried BindingList<> but it's doesn't working but I managed it by using Anonimus objects. I've just done some joins to customers, shippers and employees tables and just manual add colons to show. It worked but I'm still looking for automated way to do this.

Comment: what do you mean automated way..? I am not following you

Comment: By may way: I've manually write every column in "select new{}" block. Now, there is data like name of employee, name of customer in cells where was Model.Employee, Model.Customers etc. Do you now understand. This was not problem because there is 10 columns, but what If I had 30,100 or 1000 columns do on this way? It must be some code to fix automatically Model.Something error in cells.

Comment: please show what you are talking about you are not making this easy please show all relevant code .. also if you know the column names and they do not change then you would have to write them this way or pull the names into a variable good luck\

Answer (score 0):

My query was like this:

```
public static List<Orders> getAllOrd()
{
    var query = (from o in Model.DM_Class.dc.Orders
                 select o).ToList();
    return query;
}
```

and I didn't get any data in Customers, Employee and Shippers columns.

I re-wrote query like this:

```
public static List<Orders> getAllOrd()
{
    var query = (from o in Model.DM_Class.dc.Orders
                 join e in Model.DM_Class.dc.Employee on o.employeeID equals e.employeeID
                 select new {
                     // name all desired columns here and separate with comma 
                  }).ToList();
    return query;
}
```

After that I got data in all columns.